# Assembly in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I was trying to write a fibonacci function in mips assembly using MARS 4.5, got some wired stuff, there is a well-performed version below , but when i put code of line 1 in the place of line 2 (then eliminate code in line 1), aways returns 1 as result, why ?  What make the diference ?

```
.data   

prompt1 : .asciiz "Input a integer : \n"
prompt2 : .asciiz "The result is : \n"

.text
    .globl main

main :
    li  $v0  4
    la  $a0  prompt1
    syscall 

    li  $v0  5
    syscall 

    move  $a0  $v0

    jal  fib

    move  $t0  $v0

    li    $v0  4
    la    $a0  prompt2
    syscall

    li    $v0  1
    move  $a0  $t0
    syscall

    li  $v0  10
    syscall

fib :
    subi  $sp  $sp  12
    sw    $ra  0($sp)
    sw    $a0  4($sp)

    li   $v0  1               ############# line 1
    beq  $a0  1  final
    beq  $a0  2  final

    subi  $a0  $a0  1
    jal   fib

    sw    $v0  8($sp)

    lw    $a0  4($sp)
    subi  $a0  $a0  2
    jal   fib

    lw    $t1  8($sp)
    add   $v0  $v0  $t1


final :

       ###############                    line 2

    lw  $ra  0($sp)

    addi  $sp  $sp  12
    jr    $ra
```

Comment: _"aways returns 1 as result, why ?"_ The way the code is written, the code at `final:` is always executed, regardless of whether you're in the base case or the recursive case. Use a debugger to see how the code behaves at runtime.

Comment: You are right Michael, i realized the error i made, thank you  :)